# can you have a large number of sharded counters i.e. large number of entity kinds?

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, scalability

My question is on sharded counters and whether you could have too many.  **note the below is just a made up example.**

Say you want to keep a hit count of different pages on your site.  So to prevent datastore contention you decide to shard the hit counters for each page.  Now the number of pages grows, hence the number of sharded counters grow.

Assuming you are following the typical sharded examples, each sharded counter has its own kind allowing a query to be built that retrieves all entries blowing to a kind i.e. all entities belonging to that particular sharded counter.

My questions are:

1. Will a large number of counters (not shards per counter)
   ) affect performance as there will be so many entity kinds?
2. Is this the best practise? I mean it looks ugly in the datastore viewer when you have loads of entity kinds as each kind is a sharded counter for a page on your site.
3. If the above is not good, what would be a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you followed what you call the "typical shard counter" examples, you can see that there's only one counter type, but you can create different string keys to count different things.

That way you have only one ShardCounter type in your db, but many-many instances with different string keys.

We have a system similar to what you've described. Using only one type of counter we count more than a hundred event types, summing up to around million hits a day. So it's safe to assume that it's pretty scalable ;)

**EDIT** added counter code examples from Google's documentation:
In the last example you will a counter that has a `SHARD_KEY_TEMPLATE` variable at the top of the code. This last example allows having different counters with the same shard class.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters?hl=en

Comment: Hang on, I may need your help, I remember reading/implementing, that to count number of hits for say "event_a" you would create a counter kind of name (for example) "event_a_shards".  Then to retrieve all shards for "event_a" you execute a query to get all entities with kind "event_a_shards".  Okay I think there was another counter type just to keep track of the number of shards per counter.  Is this not how you do it?  If so then you still indeed have to have a kind per counter.

Comment: Edited the answer, look at the examples in the link

Comment: Thanks for the tip - this is great. I never noticed it because I only ever checked out the Java example.